# Drawing a regression line with interaction in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I'm trying to plot the results of a linear regression in ggplot2. I'm interested in the effect of a factorial "treatment" variable on my measurements over time. I want to calculate one slope for the time variable for each level of the "treatment" variable, but one common intercept. The function call for my linear model is:

```
lm(measurement ~ time:treatment, data = example_data)
```

However, I struggle with implementing this specific formula in the geom_smooth() function in ggplot2

This is what I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Generate an example dataset for reproduciblity:
set.seed(42)
example_data = 
data.frame(treatment   = as.factor(c(rep("t1", 50), rep("t2", 50))),
           time        = rep(1:50, 2), 
           error       = rnorm(100, 0, 1))                      %>% 
mutate(    slope       = ifelse(treatment == "t1", -0.2, -0.3)) %>% 
mutate(    measurement = 2.5 + time * slope + error)          
                  
#Linear model that I want to display in my plot: 
model = lm(measurement ~ time:treatment, data = example_data)
summary(model)

#My attempt to plot the regression line:
ggplot(data = example_data, aes(x = time, y = measurement)) + 
  geom_point()  + 
  geom_smooth(method  = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x:treatment) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment)
```

However, this does not plot any lines and returns the warning:"object treatment not found". It seems like the only variables which can be used in the "formula" argument are x and y.

Regression lines are plotted when I use "formula = y~x". However, this also generates different intercepts for each treatment.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not a statistician. Isn't it enough to plot `y ~ x`, due to the faceting `~treatment`. Wouldn't the result be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily with the `ggpredict()` function from the `ggeffects` package.  You just give it the model and tell it to get predictions for `time` and `treatment`.  Anything else in the model is held constant at a central value.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggeffects)

#Generate an example dataset for reproduciblity:
set.seed(42)
example_data = 
  data.frame(treatment   = as.factor(c(rep("t1", 50), rep("t2", 50))),
             time        = rep(1:50, 2), 
             error       = rnorm(100, 0, 1))                      %>% 
  mutate(    slope       = ifelse(treatment == "t1", -0.2, -0.3)) %>% 
  mutate(    measurement = 2.5 + time * slope + error)          

#Linear model that I want to display in my plot: 
model = lm(measurement ~ time:treatment, data = example_data)
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = measurement ~ time:treatment, data = example_data)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.2371 -0.5377  0.0119  0.7003  2.1431 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)       2.814833   0.210159   13.39   <2e-16 ***
#> time:treatmentt1 -0.214277   0.007995  -26.80   <2e-16 ***
#> time:treatmentt2 -0.307866   0.007995  -38.51   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.035 on 97 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9393, Adjusted R-squared:  0.938 
#> F-statistic: 750.2 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You can generate predictions using `ggpredict()` which produces a modified tibble.  You can call `plot()` on this object and it makes a plot with superposed lines.

```r
g <- ggpredict(model, terms=c("time", "treatment")) 

plot(g)
```

[image]

Since the result of `plot(g)` is a ggplot, you can modify it in the expected ways (e.g., adding a facet).

```r
plot(g) + facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I like `ggpredict` for some quick plotting of the regression lines, but I think a manual method can be instructive for OP in the future, so I included a base R option and `ggplot` version in my answer that takes a little more legwork (though yours is a solid option, +1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach if you want to see what is going on under the hood with the prediction lines. First you can create a sequence of values for your IV (ranging from the minimum to the maximum) while setting your other covariates to some value (here just the treatment name):

```
#### Get Prediction Data ####
nd1 <- data.frame(
  time = seq(
    min(example_data$time),
    max(example_data$time),
    length.out=200
  ),
  treatment = "t1"
) # for treatment group 1

nd2 <- data.frame(
  time = seq(
    min(example_data$time),
    max(example_data$time),
    length.out=200
  ),
  treatment = "t2"
) # for treatment group 2
```

After creating both dataframes, one for the first group and the other for the second group, you can create predictions based off those values:

```
pd1 <- predict(model,newdata=nd1)
pd2 <- predict(model,newdata=nd2)
```

Then you just have to plot the points based on group:

```
#### Plot Points ####
plot(example_data$time,
     example_data$measurement,
     xlab="Time",
     ylab="Measurement",
     main="Interaction Plot",
     pch=23,
     bg=ifelse(example_data$treatment == "t1", "steelblue",'gray'))
```

And finally overlay the lines from the predictions:

```
#### Draw Lines ####
lines(nd1$time,pd1,col="steelblue",lwd=2)
lines(nd2$time,pd2,col="gray",lwd=2)
```

Shown below:

[image]

You can see the results essentially mirror the first plot in Dave's answer. If you want your own manual plot in a `ggplot` version, you can also just do the same thing there (since that is the crux of your question):

```
#### GGPlot Version ####
example_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=time,
             y=measurement,
             fill=treatment))+
  geom_point(size=3,
             shape=23)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Time",
       y="Measurement",
       title="Interaction Plot")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue",
                                "gray"))+
  geom_line(data = nd1,
            aes(x=time,
                y=pd1),
            color = "steelblue")+
  geom_line(data = nd2,
             aes(x=time,
                 y=pd2),
             color = "gray")
```

Which gives you essentially the same thing:

[image]